# Splitting Piecewise with vectors to components

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation, piecewise

I have a piecewise function defined with vectors, e.g.

```
ab = Piecewise[{
{{a1, a2, a3}, 0 < r < 1},
{{b1, b2, b3}, 1 < r < 2}
}, {c1, c2, c3}]
```

The result of which is

```
{a1,a2,a3}  0<r<1
{b1,b2,b3}  1<r<2
{c1,c2,c3}  True
```

I'm looking for a way to address only one element of the vectors - e.g. I would like to call "ab[[1,;;]]" and get

```
a1  0<r<1
b1  1<r<2
c1  True
```

Or "ab[[2,;;]]" and get

```
a2  0<r<1
b2  1<r<2
c2  True
```

Could someone help me with the syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ab = Piecewise[{{{a1, a2, a3}, 0 < r < 1}, {{b1, b2, b3}, 
     1 < r < 2}}, {c1, c2, c3}];

abPart[n_Integer?Positive] := (ab /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {x, y, z}[[n]])

abPart[1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of piecewise expressions from `ab`:

```
splitPW = Piecewise @@@ Thread[{Thread[Thread /@ #[[1]]], #[[2]]}]&;

TeXForm /@ splitPW[ab]
```

> ${\begin{cases}
>  \text{a1} & 0<r<1 \\
>  \text{b1} & 1<r<2 \\
>  \text{c1} & \text{True}
> \end{cases},\begin{cases}
>  \text{a2} & 0<r<1 \\
>  \text{b2} & 1<r<2 \\
>  \text{c2} & \text{True}
> \end{cases},\begin{cases}
>  \text{a3} & 0<r<1 \\
>  \text{b3} & 1<r<2 \\
>  \text{c3} & \text{True}
> \end{cases}}$

and use `Part` to get the desired part:

```
splitPW[ab][[2]] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  \text{a2} & 0<r<1 \\
>  \text{b2} & 1<r<2 \\
>  \text{c2} & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

Alternatively,

```
pwPart = Module[{fpw = Internal`FromPiecewise[#], n = #2}, 
    Internal`ToPiecewise @@ {fpw[[1]], fpw[[2, All, n]]}] &;

pwPart[ab, 1]  // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  \text{a1} & 0<r<1 \\
>  \text{b1} & 1<r<2 \\
>  \text{c1} & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

Note:

```
Internal`FromPiecewise[ab]
```

> {{0 < r < 1, 1 < r < 2,  True},
>     {{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}}}

```
Internal`FromPiecewise[ab][[2]]
```

> {{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}}

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `FullForm` of `ab` we see

```
Piecewise[
  List[
    List[List[a1,a2,a3],Less[0,r,1]],List[List[b1,b2,b3],Less[1,r,2]]
  ],
  List[c1,c2,c3]
]
```

where the indentation is mine. We see that the default case is the second argument to `Piecewise`, with all other cases is in a `List` in the first argument. One way to preserve this structure is to use

```
piecePart[n_][vec_] := 
 ReplacePart[
  vec, {{1, j_, 1} :> vec[[1, j, 1, n]], 2 :> vec[[2, n]]}]
```

Example:

```
piecePart[2][ab]

a2  0 < r < 1
b2  0 1 < r < 2
c2  True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ab = Piecewise[{{{a1, a2, a3}, 0 < r < 1}, {{b1, b2, b3}, 1 < r < 2}}, {c1, c2, c3}];

pwPart[n_] := MapAt[#[[n]] &, {{1, All, 1}, {2}}]

ab // pwPart[1]
ab // pwPart[2]
ab // pwPart[3]
```

[image]